# Is there a way to do this with Mathematica shorthand notation?

Tags: functional-style, notation

I'm a big fan of Mathematica's shorthand notation, things like @ and /@, which I use the most. It's really useful when I'm quickly whipping something up.

However, something has always driven me a bit nuts. If I want to first map a function to each element in a list, and then apply another function to the whole list, like this:

```
In[338]:= a = {2, 8, 5};
SecondFn@FirstFn /@ a

Out[339]= {SecondFn[FirstFn][2], SecondFn[FirstFn][8], 
 SecondFn[FirstFn][5]}
```

You can see that it's first applying SecondFn to FirstFn, and then mapping that combination of functions to each element. I get that by default @ apparently takes precedent in the order of operations over /@, but is there an easy way to make it still go from "right to left" without using parentheses?

For example, I know I can do this to get the result I want:

```
In[340]:= a = {2, 8, 5};
SecondFn@(FirstFn /@ a)

Out[341]= SecondFn[{FirstFn[2], FirstFn[8], FirstFn[5]}]
```

But at that point I have to put a pair of parentheses, at which point I might as well just use brackets like normal (in fact it contains the extra symbol @).

Is there a way to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the operator form of Map instead:

```
SecondFn @ Map[FirstFn] @ {2, 3, 5}
```

> SecondFn[{FirstFn[2], FirstFn[3], FirstFn[5]}]

or

```
comp = SecondFn @* Map[FirstFn];
comp @ {2, 3, 5}
```

> SecondFn[{FirstFn[2], FirstFn[3], FirstFn[5]}]

Comment: Nice, that application of the operator form of `Map`! (Your second solution can also be written in one line as `SecondFn @* Map[FirstFn] @ {2, 3, 5}`.)

Comment: Thank you, this first one is exactly what I'm going for here. "right to left" and no enclosing brackets/parens.

Answer (score 13):

```
FirstFn /@ a // SecondFn
```

> ```
> SecondFn[{FirstFn[2], FirstFn[8], FirstFn[5]}]
> ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, and this is nice but still has a downside for me: it's not going "right to left". It seems like if I strung together a bunch of maps and functions I'd be bouncing around between left and right.

Answer (score 5):

A solution using only prefix notation is

```
List /* f @@ g /@ {x,y,z}
(* Out: f[{g[x],g[y],g[z]}] *)
```

*Edit.* A slightly nicer version (cf the order of the functions) uses `Composition` (`@*`) instead of the above `RightComposition` (`/*`):

```
f @* List @@ g /@ {x,y,z}
(* Out: f[{g[x],g[y],g[z]}] *)
```

This is still less elegant than the (rightfully) [accepted answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154266/29926), but it has the benefit of allowing one to use any function rather than just `List`.

Answer (score 4):

```
f2 @ Function[, f1 @ #, Listable] @ {1, 2, 3}
```

> f2[{f1[1], f1[2], f1[3]}]

We can also use `SetAttributes`

```
SetAttributes[a, Listable]
a[x_] := b @ x

c @ a @ {1, 2, 3}
```

> c[{b[1], b[2], b[3]}]

Comment: Why/how does this work? I can see that it does, even though Mma "complains" about the empty first argument of Function, and the missing & in combination with the #, by highlighting the first comma and the # in pink in my input.

Comment: If the highlighting  disturbes you try `f2@Function[Null, f1@Slot@1, Listable]@{1, 2, 3}`